# what does "V1MCC4000MEC1000MCR1000x" mean in matlab's .m file?

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with a .m file that I'm not able to read:
it starts as

V1MCC4000MEC1000MCR1000x

and that follow with many unreadable character like

漜哹逓馎(S煈KPO嘀菏戓N缻k?軥慍┎嘳鏴敕?簛ei?梤>?2;瀱啿唱煩烮?闑XSぜ时鷍徍頰r+燏p赠髬   <笉rVw拹p9_?=江秡?v
?R?RJ崀戓繝欴

What's wrong this .m file?
How could I transform it to the normal one?

Answer (score 6):

Googling the string `V1MCC4000MEC1000MCR1000x` [is enlightening](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/167857). You may have not a `.m` source file, but a compiled executable on your hands.

Here's what [Walter Robertson had to say about it](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/167857):

> The reference to MCR there suggests to me that what you have is not a
>   .m file but instead the result of running mcc to "compile" .m files (I
>   believe the output of that is a .exe file.)
>
> But without further research I would not rule out the possibility that
>   it is a matlab .ctf (Component Technology File) or .p (p-code) file.

If you do, indeed, have a compiled `.m` file, there is no way to decompile it back to the original `.m` source.